# Solve the system of linear differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Solve the initial value problem:
>   $$\dot{\mathbf{x}}=\begin{bmatrix}
> 3&-1\\
> -1&3
> \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}+\begin{bmatrix}
> 4e^{2t}\\
> 4e^{4t}
> \end{bmatrix},$$
>   with the initial condition
>   $$\mathbf{x}(0)=\begin{bmatrix}
> 1\\
> 1
> \end{bmatrix}.$$

I come up with finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and my result is
$$\bf{D}=\begin{bmatrix}
2&0\\
0&4
\end{bmatrix},\qquad
\bf{P}=\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1\\
1&-1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
But then I found that $\mathbf{P}$ is not invertible, which means that I can't figure out $e^{\mathbf{A}t}$ by using the diagonalizability of $\mathbf{A}$, where $\mathbf{A}$ is the coefficient matrix.
I have no idea what I should do next. Anyone can help?

Comment: You must have made some mistake of algebra, because eigenvectors of different eigenvalues are *always* linearly independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. I think you made some mistake somewhere in your calculation. It should be
$$D=\begin{bmatrix}
2&0\\
0&4
\end{bmatrix},\qquad
P=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\
1&-1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
So that
$$A:=\begin{bmatrix}
3&-1\\
-1&3
\end{bmatrix}=P^{-1}DP.$$
and
$$\exp(At)=P^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
e^{2t}&0\\
0&e^{4t}
\end{bmatrix}P.$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}(t)&=\exp(At)\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}+\exp(At)\int_0^t\exp(-As)\begin{bmatrix}
4e^{2s}\\
4e^{4s}
\end{bmatrix}ds\\
&=P^{-1}\left(\begin{bmatrix}
2e^{2t}\\
0
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
e^{2t}&0\\
0&e^{4t}
\end{bmatrix}\int_0^t\begin{bmatrix}
e^{-2s}&0\\
0&e^{-4s}
\end{bmatrix}P\begin{bmatrix}
4e^{2s}\\
4e^{4s}
\end{bmatrix}ds\right).
\end{align}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Oh, right! And when I continue to solve this system, I find it really complicated in calculation, such as $e^{\bf{A}t}\int_0^{t}e^{\bf{A}-x}\begin{bmatrix}4e^{2x}\\4e^{4x}\end{bmatrix}dx$. Is there any shortcut to do this?

Comment: Yes. Just this formula.

Comment: See my answer. I added a few details. The integration is not difficult. Try it!

Comment: Thanks so much. I've been evaluating such kind of integrals the whole afternoon. Drizzled all the way :)

Comment: Sorry to reply to you so late, 'cause I'm busy the whole week. My answer is $$e^{2t}\begin{bmatrix}2t-1\\ 2t+1\end{bmatrix}+e^{4t}\begin{bmatrix}2-2t\\ 2t\end{bmatrix}$$ Btw, I didn't check my answer with a computer. :)

Comment: @R.C It is correct!!